# Any update to WPF 3DTools?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 3d

I've been making heavy use of the interactive 3D controls, made by some guys on the WPF team, found here http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/Daniel-Lehenbauer-and-Kurt-Berglund-Interactive-2D-controls-on-WPF-3D-Surfaces/

I've noticed there hasn't been any updates to this lately, and with WPF and .Net 4.0 just around the corner, I was just wondering if there is a better way to do 2D controls on 3D objects, or is this still the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [Viewport2DVisual3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d.aspx).

> Viewport2DVisual3D enables you to
>   place interactive 2-D content on a 3-D
>   object. Its counterpart is the
>   Viewport3DVisual class, which is a 2-D
>   visual with 3-D children.

[EDIT] You can see an example in Matthew MacDonald's book Pro WPF in C# 2008 [here](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=XWu70Oqz6RIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=matthew+macdonald+pro+wpf+c%23+2008&cd=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false) on page 851. You may or may not be able to view it (not sure) but I won't reproduce here as it's not my work.

Comment: Thank you , thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for...time to re-write my senior project..... :)

Comment: Why do you need to derive it? Matthew MacDonald has a good example of how to use it in his book Pro WPF in C# 2008 which can be seen in Google books - I've edited my answer with link.

Comment: Or have a look at the example on the MSDN page I first linked